# line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: unix, if-statement, nested, syntax-error, nested-loops

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm coming across a syntax error while coding a shell script program in UNIX. I'm trying to create a database that allows a user to create, delete, and backup using built-in commands once the shell script is executed.

However, I'm having issues whenever using if statements or while loops. More specifically where to place the "done" or "fi" whenever I'm using a combination of both, including nesting loops. OK, here it goes.

```
> #!/bin/bash
> 
> 
> echo "*****Welcome to User Administration Program*****"
>
> for ((i=0;i<3;++i))
> #for i in `seq 1 3`
> do
>
> count=`expr $count + 1`
> echo -n "Please enter adminstrative username: "
> read input
> if [ $input == admin ]; then
> break
> if [ $count -eq 3 ]; then
> break fi fi done
> 
> 
> #so far so good
> 
> echo "Welcome admin!" echo -n "[administator@shell]$ " read userin
> while [ "$userin" = "createuser" -o "$userin" = "deleteuser" -o
> "$userin" = "ba$  do
>        command1="createuser"
>          command2="deleteuser"
>          command3="backup"
> 
> if [ "$userin" = "$command1" ]; then
>         echo "Please enter a username "
>         echo -n "[administrator@shell]$ "
> 
>  read username while read line do if  [ "$username" = "$line" ]; then
> #not reading lines correctly
>         echo "$line is taken! choose another" else
>       newUser="$username"
>         echo -n "Hello $newUser ! , enter password "
>         read passEntered
>         newPass="$passEntered"
>         echo $newUser $newPass >> userdb
>         echo "Thank you for creating password, $newUser !" <"userdb" echo "Program terminated!" exit fi done
> 
> #create user works and is completed, with exception of minor error
> 
> elif [ "$userin" == "$command2" ]; then echo "Which user do you wish
> to delete?" echo -n "[administrator@shell]$ " while    read delete do
>          username=$(echo $delete | cut -d" " -f2)
>          usernameExists=$(grep -w -c $username userdb)
>          sed -i '/$username:/d' userdb
> 
> 
> 
> if [ "$delete"  == "admin" ]; then
>          echo "You do not have necessary powers to perform this action."
>         echo "Try  again!" else command=$(echo $input | cut -d" " -f1)
> 
> dir=$(echo $input | cut -d" " -f2) fi done
> 
> 
> elif [ "$userin" == "$command3" ]; then
>          echo "How do you wish to backup?" echo -n "[administrator@shell]$ " while read input do backup=true if [
> "$input" != "$BACKUP" ]; then echo "Invalid command! Try again" fi
> 
> else #where error is happening echo "Invalid command. Please Try
> again!" fi done
```

Comment: That's really awful code formatting. Line breaks have meaning in sh scripts, but it seems you're puting them in or omitting them at random. Is the script you quote in the question really _exactly_ as the one you're executing? It looks like you should get into problems long before the `else` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `done` to match the last `while`, but you can't see it because it's buried within poorly formatted code.

Try reformatting the code, adding line breaks before the `echo` statements and indenting properly.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Sorry for the very late reply. I apologize for the format, a lot of that had to do with the copy/paste process from the terminal to this page, and not the actual coding layout in UNIX. Thanks again for the help!